# UpCasted field without access

Tags: c#, oop, object, field, upcasting

How can I access a field in a UpCasted Object? I cannot use Console.WriteLine in order to print `SuperPower` property of a `Guy` object

```
namespace Test
{
    class Guy
    {
        public int Power { get; set; }
    }

    class BigGuy : Guy
    {
        public int SuperPower { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guy guy = new Guy();
            BigGuy bigGuy = new BigGuy();
            bigGuy.SuperPower = 4;
            guy = bigGuy;
            Console.WriteLine(guy.SuperPower); // Visual studio doesn't accept this line.
        }
    }
}
```

When i debug I get an error:

```
'Guy' does not contain a definition for 'SuperPower'
```

Why can't I access `guy.SuperPower` field?

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `guy` to `BigGuy` before accessing fields of `BigGuy` class:

```
Console.WriteLine(((BigGuy)guy).SuperPower);
```

Comment: Okay, I kinda understand that, but why is there addicional bracket, I mean why  Console.WriteLine((BigGuy)guy.SuperPower); doesn't work either?

Comment: `(BigGuy)guy.SuperPower` is the same as `(BigGuy)(guy.SuperPower)`

Comment: @K.Zoyar Extra brackets are required because otherwise you will try cast the value of `guy.SuperPower` to class `SuperGuy` instead of casting `guy` object

Comment: Oh, I see now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of the variable is `Guy`. Which means you only have access to properties declared on the `Guy` type.

Imagine if you had a second subclass:

```
class FastGuy : Guy
{
    public int SpeedPower { get; set; }
}

guy = bigGuy;
guy = new FastGuy();
```

The properties you would be able to access would change depending on what value you're assigning. That would mean it wouldn't be able to do type checking at compile time.

Typically, the point of declaring a type as some less specific type is so that you can act on the object as though it were that type, even though the concrete type may be a subclass.

Comment: Okay, i didn't know that you can change access by assigning different values, thanks!